# Ubuntu 21.10 - Dock menu and the applications disappeared

Tags: settings, dock, 21.10

After updating to the latest Ubuntu 21.10, the dock menu has completely disappeared.

ubuntu 20.04 with dock:

[image: ubuntu 20.04]

ubuntu 21.10 dock disappeared:

[image: ubuntu 21.10]

Comment: Try to reinstall the dock extension from here https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/307/dash-to-dock/

Comment: ... and to log out and log in back...

Answer (score 0):

Bonjour,

I have the same problem. It appears after a sleep seesion or if the computer is left idle for a while.
Launcher remains active as long as the user is active.
Need to close the session and reopen it to retreive the launcher.